# Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.."

Tags: c#, .net, rest

I am sending the JSON data through the REST API POST method.
Getting "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException". Could you help with this?

await Post(requestUri, json, Token);

Comment: Is APi yours? Is it listening? Are you using the good port? Are you doing calculation during the post?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.